# regex intermediate

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that is formatted like so: `"SomeText ($4.56)"`

I am using the following regex `\${1}[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*` to pull out currency data but it includes the `$` sign.

I am intermediate and understand this as.

- `\$` is looking for The dollar sign
- `[0-9]+` is any number of digits after
- `\.` is finding the decimal
- `*[0-9]*` is finding zero or more digits after the decimal

I want the dollar sign removed though. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language or tool?

Comment: javascript using exec

Comment: Try `str.replace(/\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b/g, '$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very simple... Just use **groups**!

It will look like this:

```
\$([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)
```

And group 1 will return the currency without the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing good but removing a substring in JS with regex needs calling `.replace()` method. Regex:

```
\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

Breakdown:

- `\$` Macth a literal dollar sign
- `(` Start of capturing group one

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a sequence of digits with optional decimals
- `)` End of of capturing group
- `\b` Match a word boundary

JS code:

```js
var str = "SomeText ($4.56)";
console.log(str.replace(/\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: I agree and did use that but it was unacceptable for people I work with. Wanted it all done in regex.

Comment: Well, it is  all regex.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the stuff you want in brackets to create a capture group.

```
\$(\d+\.\d{2})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PUENaE/1)

```js
var regex = /\$(\d+\.\d{2})/;
var string = "SomeText ($4.56)";
var matches = regex.exec(string);

console.log(matches); // all matches
console.log(matches[1]); // first capture group
```